# powershell wrong results for file length

Tags: powershell

I have a file with length of 309247 bytes as this image:
[image]

If I run this powershell script:

```
(Get-Item 'C:\TestFile.082').length
309247
```

But if run the same script but a `$file` variable it returns this:

```
$fpath = Get-Item $file.FullName
$fpath.length 
309800
# or 
(Get-Item $file.FullName).length
309800
# or
$file.length 
309800
```

**NOTE** $file is a variable into a loop for all files contained in a directory

Why if I'm referencing the same file the results are different?

How can I do to get the real value (309247)?

This is my Full Code

```
$filesToFtp = Get-Item  $pathToFtp -Exclude "*.PreARM"  
foreach($file in $filesToFtp)
{
    $fpath = Get-Item $file.FullName
    $fpath.Length

    $FileNode = $oXMLDocumentFiles.CreateElement("element","curtmpremotelxml_files","")
    $nodoXML = "<versionnum>"+$versplain+"</versionnum>"+
                "<filename>"+$file.Name.ToUpper()+"</filename>"+
                "<filesize>"+$file.length+".00</filesize>"+
    $FileNode.InnerXml = $nodoXML
    $oXMLDocumentFiles.DocumentElement.AppendChild($FileNode)   
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Apparently you're looking at a different file.

Comment: Please show the code where `$file` is set. I also can't reproduce this and agree you're probably looking at a different file.

Comment: I still can't reproduce. Using `.length` is the correct method of getting the file size. Maybe your path contains `[` and `]`? If so, those are treated as wildcards.

Comment: `$fpath = Get-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't using the cmdlet you think you are:

```
 foreach( $file in (Get-Item 'c:\')) { ($file.FullName).Length }
```

is a condensed version of your variable to fill $fPath, but what it returns is a System.IO.FileSystemInfo object, of which there is a member called FullPath, a string.

What I assume you want it

```
foreach( $file in (Get-ChildItem 'c:\')) { ($file.FullName).Length }
```

which would return an Array of filepaths of the child items (or files within the folder)

This would also let you clean up a few things

```
$currentFilePath = $file.FullName
$fLength = $currentFilePath.Length
```